# How to dynamically resize applet components when the window changed?

Tags: java, applet

i tried the following code to display an image on applet, but when i tried to change the size pf the applet window the loaded image doesn't resized, why that happen?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ImageViewer extends Applet
{
    Image image;
    int imageX, imageY;
    MediaTracker mt;

    public void init()
    {
        showStatus("Getting image...");
        mt = new MediaTracker(this);
        image = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "fruits.jpg");
        mt.addImage(image, 0);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        showStatus("Loading image...");
        try
        {
            mt.waitForAll();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(!mt.checkAll(true)){}
        imageX = image.getWidth(this);
        imageY = image.getHeight(this);
        showStatus("Resizing Applet image size: " + imageX + "x" + imageY);
        resize(imageX, imageY);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        showStatus("Drawing image...");
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because you're not actually resizing the image in any way

Comment: *"How to dynamically resize applet components when the window changed?"*  Typically the window size of an applet would not change.  An applet should never try to resize itself from Java code.  BTW - Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image doesn't resize as you're using the `Graphics.drawImage` method which uses the images own size instead of the size of the `Applet` container

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```

You could replace this with

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

Also don't forget to call

```
super.paint(g);
```

to draw any child components including the container background.

---

BTW: `java.awt.Applet` is something of a relic now, having been replaced by [JApplet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html). This is part of [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) which uses lightweight resources and has many more features.

Comment: (Don't forget to call super.paint ;))